# fullcalendar plugin does not add events from array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

basically any hard coded values will work.  However, when I build an array of even object and then set it, no events are added to the calendar.

```
           function getCalendarEvents() {
           var events = new Array();
           $(".ms-srch-item:visible").each(function () {
                   events.push(
                       {
                           title: $(this).find(".assigned_resource").html(),
                           start: new Date($(this).find(".start_date").attr("date")),
                           end: new Date($(this).find(".end_date").attr("date"))
                   });
           });
           return events;
       }

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#testme").click(function () {
               var array = [{ title: 'All Day Event', start: new Date(2013, 8, 5)  }];
               array = getCalendarEvents();
               var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                   header: {
                       left: 'prev,next today',
                       center: 'title',
                       right: 'month,agendaWeek'
                   },
                   events:array
               });

               $(".fc-button-agendaWeek").click(function () {
                   $(".fc-agenda-allday").next().next().hide();

               });
           });
       });
```

I have checked the array object and it is in the correct form with proper values.  But for some reason I get no events.  If I dont use the function and use the hard coding it works for that one event.  See any problems with my code?

EDIT:

here is working code (ignore color stuff that I added):

```
function getCalendarEvents() {

           if(calendarColors.length < 1)
           {
               //build colors first time ...do it here because we want to wait for async clients call to finish 
               BuildCalendarColorsMap();
           }
           var events = new Array();

           $(".ms-srch-item:visible").each(function () {
               var client = $(this).find(".client").html();
               //junk check testing
               if (client && client.indexOf('<strong>Client:</strong>') != -1) {
                   client = client.replace('<strong>Client:</strong>', '');
                   var start = new Date($(this).find(".start_date").attr("date"));
                   var end = new Date($(this).find(".end_date").attr("date"));
                   var title = client + ": " + $(this).find(".assigned_resource").html().replace('<strong>Assigned Resource:</strong>', "");
                   var color = getCalendarColor(client);
                   events.push(
                       {
                           title: title,
                           start: new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate()),
                           end: new Date(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate()),
                           color: color
                       });
               }
           });
           return events;
       }
```

Comment: What is the output if you execute `console.log(events);` in the end of `getCalendarEvents()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the string for the `start` and `end` attributes.

> The string may be in ISO8601 format, IETF format, or a UNIX timestamp
>   (in either integer or string form).

[FullCalendar/docs/parseDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/parseDate/)

Comment: I'll give the the correct answer but its weird I use script to set the date attr to a javascript date.  Then it does not parse into the correct one.  So what I had to do was add a couple lines to call the date constructor again.  Thanks though for your input and helping me get to the answer.